# python getting weekday from an input date

Tags: python, date

I'm trying to work on a homework problem where I have an input date in the format YYYY-MM-DD

I need to import a couple modules and create a function weekday where it splits up the date and returns the weekday.

So far I imported:

```
from time import *
from datetime import *
```

I need help in my weekday function where I must use a `.split` method

Create an object of the class `datetime.date`.
and use `strftime` to return the day of the week in full text.

Can anyone help me get started on how to implement these functions and modules properly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose `s` is your input string:

```
s = '2010-10-29'
```

At the prompt, try `s.split('-')`. What happens?

Create a `date` object:

```
d = datetime.date(2010, 10, 29)
```

Then run `d.strftime('%B')`. What happens? How would you get the weekday, instead?

You can fill in the rest. Look at the Python docs for more information. [Python doc: time](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html), [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html)

Comment: TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'str'

Answer (score 2):

it's two lines

```
import time
print time.strftime("%A", time.strptime('2010-10-29', "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

prints 'Friday'

Comment: When someone asks for help and you give them the entire code, you are not only not helping them learn, you are also disrepecting their questions. They didn't ask for the entire code.