# Convert dataframe column to string to apply strftime

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, datetime

I would like to create a `weekday` column from a another column `Date` in dataframe `df`:

```
        id      timestamp               data    Date
27001   27242   2020-01-01 09:07:21.277 19.5    2020-01-01
27002   27243   2020-01-01 09:07:21.377 19.0    2020-01-01
27581   27822   2020-01-02 07:53:05.173 19.5    2020-01-02
```

with code

```
df['Date'] = pd.Series(df['Date'], dtype="string")

# df['Date'] = pd.Series(df['Date'], dtype=pd.StringDtype)
# df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
datetime.datetime.strptime(df['Date'], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%A')
```

based on these posts:
[post1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60553529/11901732)
[post2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22006514/11901732)

but incurred error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-bd59bae0ddd9> in <module>()
      3 
      4 # df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
----> 5 datetime.datetime.strptime(df['Date'], '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%A')
      6 # type(df['Date'])

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series
```

What is the best way to create a `"day of week"` column from column `Date`?

---

Update:

Tried

```
df['Weekday'] = df['Date'].weekday
```

which returned

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-f788d4a4608d> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 df['Weekday'] = df['Date'].weekday

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5273                 return self[name]
-> 5274             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5275 
   5276     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'weekday'
```

then tried

```
df['Weekday'] = df['Date'].dt.weekday
```

which returned

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-592865ef8c59> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 df['Weekday'] = df['Date'].dt.weekday

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/accessors.py in __new__(cls, data)
    336             return DatetimeProperties(data, orig)
    337 
--> 338         raise AttributeError("Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values")

AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: `df['Weekday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%A'))`

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik thank you that worked, actually I would like to insert `weekday` in a plot title as of https://stackoverflow.com/q/60922726/11901732. Can I apply this solution in that question?

Comment: Oooh, yes that's an even better solution. Why did you ask this question then?

Comment: @VorsprungdurchTechnik That was the actual question I wanted to solve but got stuck. So had to step back and rethink about a different approach..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the initial dataframe where datatype of `Date` column is `str` , you can do :

```
df['Weekday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).apply(lambda x : x.weekday())
```

Another way is :

```
df['Weekday'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.weekday
```

Answer (score 1):

Your column `df['Weekday']` isn't of type `Datetime` yet. Only then can you call the method `.dt`.

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

should fix that.

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. Ps. I think you meant `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` ?